# TimePickerDialog for a length - Android

Tags: android, time, dialog, timepicker

I would like to use a TimePickerDialog to enter a length instead of a time,

So I would use the same functionalities of a TimePicker but without the PM/AM and to be able to select more than 24 hours

Thanks!

SDK: 2.1

Comment: You have no option than to implement your own dialog. You didn't say for what SDK version do you develop, starting with Honeycomb(API 11) you have the `NumberPicker` view that you could use in a custom dialog. If you want to develop for previous version of android then you have no options than to implement your own dialog + number picker(but if you google maybe you could find something already built).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use spinners?

```
//Hour Spinner Values
    String[] hours = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
            "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12" ... "24" };

//Hour Spinner
     final Spinner hourspinner = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.hourspinner);
     ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hours);
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     hourspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
     hourspinner.setSelection(mHour);
```

You can make spinner for Days/Hours/Minutes/Seconds and then do whatever you need with values taken from the spinners. You can get the value by:

```
String hourvalue = hourspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

And you could contain them in a custom alertdialog if you want to emulate a similiar feel to the popup that TimePickerDialog has.

Comment: I think it will be too much work to do this to look like the time picker, but yes it's a solution to keep in mind. thanks !